# Fixar linhas em tabela

Tags: html, css, table

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```css
.mytable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header, .footer {
  //position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="mytable">
   <tr class="header">
     <th rowspan="2">H1</th>
     <th colspan="3">H2</th>
     <th rowspan="2">H3</th>
     <th rowspan="2">H4</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="header">
     <th>H2.1</th>
     <th>H2.2</th>
     <th>H2.3</th>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td>I1 H1</td>
     <td>I1 H2</td>
     <td>I1 H3</td>
     <td>I1 H4</td>
     <td>I1 H5</td>
     <td>I1 H6</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td>I2 H1</td>
     <td>I2 H2</td>
     <td>I2 H3</td>
     <td>I2 H4</td>
     <td>I2 H5</td>
     <td>I2 H6</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td>I3 H1</td>
     <td>I3 H2</td>
     <td>I3 H3</td>
     <td>I3 H4</td>
     <td>I3 H5</td>
     <td>I3 H6</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td>I4 H1</td>
     <td>I4 H2</td>
     <td>I4 H3</td>
     <td>I4 H4</td>
     <td>I4 H5</td>
     <td>I4 H6</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td>I5 H1</td>
     <td>I5 H2</td>
     <td>I5 H3</td>
     <td>I5 H4</td>
     <td>I5 H5</td>
     <td>I5 H6</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td>I6 H1</td>
     <td>I6 H2</td>
     <td>I6 H3</td>
     <td>I6 H4</td>
     <td>I6 H5</td>
     <td>I6 H6</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr class="footer">
     <th>FH1</th>
     <th>FH2</th>
     <th>FH3</th>
     <th>FH4</th>
     <th>FH5</th>
     <th>FH6</th>
   </tr>
   
</table>
```

Eu gostaria de fixar o cabeçalho e rodapé e disponibilizar o scroll.

Minha pergunta foge um pouco do contexto das perguntas semelhantes, pois mesclo linhas no cabeçalho.

O resultado desejado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Considerando o scroll e o alinhamento das colunas.

Eu gostaria muito de usar apeans uma tabela.

Comment: Não entendi. O que você quer fazer?

Comment: colocar o scroll na tabela e deixar o cabeçalho e rodapé fixos...

Answer (score 1):

Antes de tudo que tal organizar a sua tabela?

Utilize as tags  [thead, tbody e tfoot](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-thead-element) para melhor organização da sua tabela. Leia mais sobre isso [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33278779/4843158)

Já a resposta que procura, seria algo parecido com isso?

```css
.mytable {
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.mytable tr {
  display: flex;
}
.mytable td {
  padding: 3px;
  flex: 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 1px;
  word-wrap: break;
}

.mytable thead th {
  flex: 1 auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.mytable tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th rowspan="2">H1</th>
      <th colspan="3">H2</th>
      <th rowspan="2">H3</th>
      <th rowspan="2">H4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>H2.1</th>
      <th>H2.2</th>
      <th>H2.3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I2 H1</td>
      <td>I2 H2</td>
      <td>I2 H3</td>
      <td>I2 H4</td>
      <td>I2 H5</td>
      <td>I2 H6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I3 H1</td>
      <td>I3 H2</td>
      <td>I3 H3</td>
      <td>I3 H4</td>
      <td>I3 H5</td>
      <td>I3 H6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I4 H1</td>
      <td>I4 H2</td>
      <td>I4 H3</td>
      <td>I4 H4</td>
      <td>I4 H5</td>
      <td>I4 H6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I5 H1</td>
      <td>I5 H2</td>
      <td>I5 H3</td>
      <td>I5 H4</td>
      <td>I5 H5</td>
      <td>I5 H6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I6 H1</td>
      <td>I6 H2</td>
      <td>I6 H3</td>
      <td>I6 H4</td>
      <td>I6 H5</td>
      <td>I6 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I1 H1</td>
      <td>I1 H2</td>
      <td>I1 H3</td>
      <td>I1 H4</td>
      <td>I1 H5</td>
      <td>I1 H6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfooter>
    <tr class="footer">
      <th>FH1</th>
      <th>FH2</th>
      <th>FH3</th>
      <th>FH4</th>
      <th>FH5</th>
      <th>FH6</th>
      <tr>
  </tfooter>

</table>
```

Se for isso, a linha que realmente faz o trabalho é essa:

```
.mytable tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Onde você seta o `height` e o `overflow-y`.

Para mais informações, veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11891065/4843158).

Bom, isso é feito apenas com CSS e gera um segundo scroll.

Porém, se quiser fazer com javascript, existem [vários códigos prontos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673153/4843158) ensinando como fazer.

Comment: É exatamente isso @Randrade e muito obrigado pela dica da organização. Só não consigo trabalhar bem com o alinhamento, pois veja que em seu código está diferente do original...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Isso nada mais é do que CSS. Basta remover as demais linhas que achar desnecessário para o layout que irá ficar da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoalmente eu usaria uma div fixada no topo com uma tabela com os cabeçalhos e abaixo outra div com a tabela com conteúdo, assim o scroll fica fácil e criado pelo próprio navegador.

Comment: O problema é o alinhamento, apesar de eu ter exemplificado com um código fixo, as colunas da tabela são dinâmicas, o que dificultaria um pouco mais trabalhar com divs.

Comment: Entendi! Nesse caso o modelo do @Randrade ou usar plugins...